# Что положить в Post запрос?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, post, httpclient

Имеем сайт с формами для заполнения и кнопками, как узнать тип параметра, название и какие значения может принимать? Для отправки post запроса.
Например берем этот сайт http://pegast.ru/callback, как будет выглядеть post-запрос, передающий заполненные поля и нажатие на кнопку.

Comment: Если есть сайт с формами для заполнения, то надо на эти формы и смотреть. Какие там элементы есть, такие параметры и сможете принимать. Скорее всего данные придут строкой, хотя не уверен что это верно для всех языков. Вам лучше указать какой конкретно вас интересует и что именно вызывает у вас проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используется `<form action="xxx">`, то вероятнее всего, ключи POST-запроса будут равны свойству "name" полей формы.

Данный пример это хорошо показывает: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Я надеюсь, я правильно понял вас.

Comment: да, вы верно меня поняли. Не подскажите в post запросе выглядит нажатие кнопки

Comment: Я думаю, что никак, однако извиняюсь, не могу точно ответить, поскольку не знаю.